# USERNAME-VBA-ACCESS

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have been asked to create a field(FORM) in access that get the USERNAME who has logged in . I created the string VBA   `Me!EmployeeID = Environ("USERNAME")` which is on load. However, I noticed when I click on next record it goes way and wont get updated. I am not VBA expert that why I am here. What string should I write and where should I put it?
Should it be on form properties or the `Employee ID` field properties and also which part Before update or After?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. All you've done is repeat information that is already in the tags. Your title should explain the problem you're having or question you're asking, in a way that is specific enough to be useful to a future reader here who is scanning a list of search results. In addition, your question is far too vague. We can't tell you why your code isn't working, because you've not included any of your code.

Comment: Try the form BeforeUpdate event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use form **Current** event. This event occurs both when a form is opened and whenever the focus leaves one record and moves to another

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me!EmployeeID = Environ("USERNAME")
End Sub
```

Comment: I have another problem, if I go to the previous record the username will be overwrite by my username. how can I lock the entry in the database

Comment: @SheidaBadvipour   Kindly click on checkmark next to answer if the solution was helpful.